# No user defined transport headers in pulled messages from queue OSB JMS WLS

Tags: jms, message-queue, weblogic11g, osb

im facing a problem with my jms messeages.
Case is:
in my mainPS i give an employeeId on request which routes to BS to get employees with emploeeId >= than given. Response is employees collecion. 
On response action in mainPS I loop through whole collection and  id like to add to JMS queue one by one employee as simple message. In every loop iteration im seting user-defined transport header in if statement as msgName 'even' or 'odd' depends on employeeId on Outbound Request. On loged result i can see that headers have added properly.
Then (still for every employee) I publish my JMS-BS which adds message to queue. 
When I want to pull my messages in JMSConsumerPS there are no any transport headers which i have added. Consumer has Get All Headers property set as 'YES'.
Im logging in consumer my whole

```
$inbound/ctx:transport
```

and what i get is:

```
<con:transport>
<con:uri>myURI</con:uri>
<con:mode>request</con:mode>
<con:qualityOfService>best-effort</con:qualityOfService>
<con:request xsi:type="jms:JmsRequestMetaData" xmlns:jms="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports/jms" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <tran:headers xsi:type="jms:JmsRequestHeaders" xmlns:tran="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports">
    <jms:JMSDeliveryMode>2</jms:JMSDeliveryMode>
    <jms:JMSExpiration>0</jms:JMSExpiration>
    <jms:JMSMessageID>ID:&lt;834866.1398327222060.0></jms:JMSMessageID>
    <jms:JMSPriority>4</jms:JMSPriority>
    <jms:JMSRedelivered>false</jms:JMSRedelivered>
    <jms:JMSTimestamp>1398327222060</jms:JMSTimestamp>
    <jms:JMSXDeliveryCount>1</jms:JMSXDeliveryCount>
  </tran:headers>
  <tran:encoding xmlns:tran="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports">UTF-8</tran:encoding>
  <jms:message-type>Text</jms:message-type>
</con:request>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Could you attach the project or possibly screenshots of it?

Comment: Are you sure that message have user-defined headers attached when it goes to queue? Please check the message while it is still in queue (disable the polling proxy or consumption of queue itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess.

> I was setting transport header in in-correct place. I had a "publish"
>   action in the proxy and I was setting transport header just before the
>   publish action. I moved the "transport header setting" to be done
>   inside the "publish" action/task . Now it works as expected.

Taken from https://community.oracle.com/thread/2155298?tstart=165, link most likely will be dead soon enough - Oracle community ...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for that. That was almost same issue. What I did was movig "transport header setting" into request action of published BS. Thing is i have tried it before asking but had no idea why it didnt work. Probably the reason could be that i turned on pass all headers through pipeline that time  [?]. Had no idea if that can make such a mess. Thanks for replaying.